# How to output the sum function into a cell

Tags: vba, excel, sum, range

I'm writing a code that will add a new employee to a list of employees and update all of the sum functions below those employees.  I've searched for a few days on this site and can't seem to find anyone who's having the same exact problem.

Once the employee's name and hours have been added in the new row, I need the subtotals at the bottom to include the new row in it's calculation of total hours.

I've looped down to the row using a for...next loop, with x changing.

I got as far as getting this to output into my sheet.  It's logically correct, but doesn't actually work. It's just to give an idea of what I'm trying to do.

=SUM(Range(Cells(5, 17), Cells( x, 17)))

At the end I just want something like this to show up in the subtotal cell...
=SUM(Q5:Q18)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Where is the code you are doing this? That will help significantly. I suspect you can use `Range(Cells(5, 17), Cells( x, 17)).Address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()

   dim x as Integer

    For x = 5 To 17
        Cells(x, 18) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(5, 17), Cells(x, 17)))
    Next
End Sub
```

OR

If you want to send formula as a string you can use the below.

```
Sub sample()

   dim x as Integer

    For x = 5 To 17
        Cells(x, 18) = "=Sum(Q5:Q" & x & ")"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! The second version of the code is exactly what I needed!  I can't vote this up yet apparently because I need 15 reputation to do that...