# How to calculate the sum of a textbox value and print it to a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I calculate the value of a text box and print it to a cell in Microsoft Excel VBA?

For example: I enter 2*2 into my textbox, and I want it to print 4 to a cell.

the textbox is in a userform this is what i have so far, although it works it doesn't look nice. I'm new to excel so help is appreciated.

```
 Private Sub Submit_Click() 
 Dim str As String 
 Dim bracket As String 
 lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
 str = "=SUM(" 
 bracket = ")" 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
 Sheets("Value").Activate 
 Cells(lastrow, 1) = str & txtbox.Value & bracket 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Where is this textbox? is it in a `UserForm` or on your sheet? what type of textbox is it? A screen shoot would help. Unfortunately you haven't provided enough information. Please read: [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: With VBA you could just set a cell's formula to whatever is in the text box like `Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula = "=" & TextBox1.Value` You could also use `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Application.Evaluate(TextBox1.Value)` in VBA to evaluate the result and just stick the result directly in the cell.

Comment: the textbox is in a userform this is what i have so far, although it works it doesn't look nice. I'm new to excel so help is appreciated.

`Private Sub Submit_Click()

Dim str As String

Dim bracket As String

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

str = "=SUM("

bracket = ")"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Value").Activate

Cells(lastrow, 1) = str & txtbox.Value & bracket
`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947648/how-to-output-the-sum-function-into-a-cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fully Qualify your Objects.**

Currently, you are writing `Cells(lastrow, 1) = str & txtbox.Value & bracket`

Excel is *implictly* treating this as `ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 1).Value = str & txtbox.Value & bracket` - because you only provide half the information, it has to guess.  It assumes you want the `ActiveSheet`, and it assumes you want to change the `Value`.  But, you **don't**.

To put a `Formula` into a `Cell` in VBA, don't use `Value` - use `Formula`, like so:  `ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow,1).Formula = str & txtbox.Value & bracket`

Alternatively, if you want the `Value`, but not the `Formula`, then there are 2 methods.  Either convert the result, like so:

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 1)
    .Formula = str & txtbox.Value & bracket
    .Calculate
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Or use the [`Application.Evaluate` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 1).Value = EVALUATE(str & txtbox.Value & bracket)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Private Sub Submit_Click()
  With Sheets("Value")
    .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1 ,0).formula = "=" & me.txtbox
  End With
End Sub
```

I assume that the textbox is called txtbox and that the routine is being run from a button on the same userform